# What's the best way to tell the missing row in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python - pandas, currently trying to use it to check whether the data in DataFrame is continuous. For example:

```
    thread  sequence      start      end
14       1       114    1647143  1672244
15       1       115    1672244  1689707
16       1       116    1689707  1713090
17       1       118    1735352  1760283
18       1       119    1760283  1788062
19       1       120    1788062  1789885
20       1       121    1789885  1790728
```

Every row owns 4 columns, in general sequence should be increased with step of 1, so if everything is correct, it would look like 116,117,118 ... , like a range() function. But example here missing the row with sequence == 117.

I tried to find it, but I don't know how to do it. If I just check the sequence one by one, it would be inefficient. The desired output would be to tell the missing row or fill the missing row with NaN.

Any good tips or suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A faster method using `RangeIndex`:

```
seq = pd.RangeIndex(df.sequence.min(), df.sequence.max())
seq[~seq.isin(df.sequence)].values
# array([117])
```

Comment: @Castor If you just want the values and not the data frame, you shouldn't use the accepted answer. It is very slow.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Yes, I notice you said the 'fastest method', it seems like much slower to get a DataFrame then find the NaN inside, I will do a benchmark to test it later. Thanks for tip.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to get the missing sequence values you can do something like this:

```
>>> seq = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(df.iloc[0].sequence, df.iloc[-1].sequence))
>>> seq[~seq[0].isin(df.sequence)]
    0
3   117
```

Comment: Yes, missing value is the the desired output, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I wish to see your desired output but please check below.

```
test = df.set_index('sequence').reindex(range(df['sequence'].min(), df['sequence'].max())).reset_index()
print(test)

   sequence  thread      start        end
0       114     1.0  1647143.0  1672244.0
1       115     1.0  1672244.0  1689707.0
2       116     1.0  1689707.0  1713090.0
3       117     NaN        NaN        NaN
4       118     1.0  1735352.0  1760283.0
5       119     1.0  1760283.0  1788062.0
6       120     1.0  1788062.0  1789885.0

print(test[test['thread'].isnull()]['sequence'].tolist())

[117]
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful in understanding how to reset index with pandas

Comment: Sorry for I re-select the answer since it was faster , but anyway your way is much easier to understand, thanks for that !

Comment: @Castor No problem! Using `RangeIndex` is much better answer indeed.